# Magento2 not reading my requirejs-config.js

Tags: requirejs, magento2

I'm new to Magento2 and trying to figure out how RequireJS works in Magento.

Here is my situation:

I have following module:

```
app/code/Mymodule/Test/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

Here is the content of this file:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        jQuery110: "Mymodule_Test/js/jquery-1.10.2",
        jqueryNoConflict: 'Mymodule_Test/js/jquery.no-conflict',
        flexslider: 'Mymodule_Test/js/jquery.flexslider-min',
        header: 'Mymodule_Test/js/store/header'
    }
}
};
```

My theme is at this location:

```
app/design/frontend/Mycompany/Basic
```

My Javascripts are at following location:

```
app/code/Mymodule/Test/view/frontend/web/js/jquery.no-conflict.js
app/code/Mymodule/Test/view/frontend/web/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js
app/code/Mymodule/Test/view/frontend/web/js/store/header.js
```

In the PHTML file:

```
app/code/Mymodule/Test/view/frontend/templates/home.phtml
```

I added the lines:

```
require(['jqueryNoConflict', 'flexslider'],function($, flexslider){
    (function($) {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider();
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

When I check my page in browser, I get 404 error with paths:

```
http://mag2.com.local/pub/static/frontend/Mycompany/Basic/en_US/flexslider.js
```

But if I change the require[] line to this:

```
require(['Mymodule_Test/js/jquery.no-conflict', 'Mymodule_Test/js/jquery.flexslider-min'],function($, flexslider){
    (function() {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider();
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
```

the files are loading.

I also cleared the cache, my theme is correct, I executed the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

So, I am not able to figure out why my requirejs-config.js is not loading. I followed the documentation as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the problem.

Under **pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Namespace/Theme/en_US**, delete the file **requirejs-config.js**.

Refresh your page and it will be generated again with new content.

Comment: on version 2.2.3 in production mode, I deleted all the requirejs-config.js files under pub/static, `find pub/static -iname requirejs-config.js`. They were not in a _requirejs directory but in e.g. pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js . Then a setup:static-content:deploy, flush cache, hard refresh, and the module's file was included.

Comment: you can also use the command line. php bin/magento setup:upgrade did the job. but thanks for the hint. saved me a lot of time

Comment: life saving, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may help someone else with a very similar issue on local with nginx. The /static block was not rewriting correctly and this needed to be added per this comment https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7869#issuecomment-268585438

```
location /static/ {
    if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
      expires max;
    }

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
      rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
      expires +1y;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
      }
    }

    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
      expires off;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
         rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
      }
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
```

Comment: life saver answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The detailed explanation is [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Refused-to-apply-style-quot-because-its-MIME-type-text-html-is/m-p/86746/highlight/true#M4063)

As requested by other members, adding the important bits:

Check if you can find the file it's trying to load on the filesystem. If it's there, it would point to a web server configuration problem instead. If it's not check file permission and then do static content deploy.